# void serialEvent Arduino - Processing to avoid lag

Tags: serial-port, arduino, processing

I'm having problems with sending data from Arduino to Processing. I can receive the data OK in the draw loop, but it was very slow, so I included a serialEvent() function to try and eliminate some of the lagginess, but now it doesn't seem to be reading the data in the serialEvent function, and I can't figure out why!

```
import themidibus.*;
import processing.serial.*;

int end = 10;
String serial;
Serial port;
MidiBus myBus;

// Incoming data
int c;
int d;
int e;
int f;
int g;
int a;
int b;
int C;
int pitchPot;
int tonalityPot;
int noteVol;
int pan;
int reverb;
int dlay;
int distort;
int octave;

// Ellipse parameters
int noteOn = 0;
int col1 = 0;
int col2 = 0;
int col3 = 0;

int passTime;
int saveTime;
int expand = 0;
String[] A = new String[18];
String[] B = new String[18];

boolean cPress = false;
boolean dPress = false;
boolean ePress = false;
boolean fPress = false;
boolean gPress = false;
boolean aPress = false;
boolean bPress = false;
boolean CPress = false;

void setup() {
  size(600, 600, P3D);
  frameRate(10);
  smooth();
  port = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[6], 115200);
  port.clear();
  serial = port.readStringUntil(end);
  serial = null; // Initially, the string will be null (empty)
  myBus = new MidiBus(this, -1, "Java Sound Synthesizer");
}

void draw() {

  if ((c == 1) && (cPress == false)) {
    col1 = 255;
    col2 = 0;
    col3 = 0;
    myBus.sendControllerChange(1, 10, pan);
    myBus.sendNoteOn(1, (60 + pitchPot + octave), noteVol);
    cPress = true;
  }

  if ((c == 0) && (cPress == true)) {
    myBus.sendNoteOff(1, (60 + pitchPot + octave), noteVol);
    cPress = false;
  }
  // D

  if ((d == 1) && (dPress == false)) {
    col1 = 0;
    col2 = 0;
    col3 = 255;
    myBus.sendControllerChange(1, 10, pan);
    myBus.sendNoteOn(1, (62 + pitchPot + octave), noteVol);
    dPress = true;
  }

  if ((d == 0) && (dPress == true)) {
    myBus.sendNoteOff(1, (62 + pitchPot + octave), noteVol);
    dPress = false;
  }

  if ((e == 1) && (ePress == false)){
    col1 = 0;
    col2 = 255;
    col3 = 0;
    myBus.sendControllerChange(1, 10, pan);
    myBus.sendNoteOn(1, (64 + pitchPot + tonalityPot  + octave), noteVol);
    ePress = true;
  }

  if ((e == 0) && (ePress == true)){
    myBus.sendNoteOff(1, (64 + pitchPot  + tonalityPot + octave), noteVol);
    ePress = false;
  }

  if ((f == 1) && (fPress == false)) {
    col1 = 255;
    col2 = 0;
    col3 = 255;
    myBus.sendControllerChange(1, 10, pan);
    myBus.sendNoteOn(1, (65 + pitchPot + octave), noteVol);
    fPress = true;
  }

  if ((f == 0) && (fPress == true)) {
    myBus.sendNoteOff(1, (65 + pitchPot + octave), noteVol);
    fPress = false;
  }

  if ((g == 1) && (gPress == false)) {
    col1 = 255;
    col2 = 255;
    col3 = 0;
    myBus.sendControllerChange(1, 10, pan);
    myBus.sendNoteOn(1, (67 + pitchPot + octave), noteVol);
    gPress = true;
  }

  if ((g == 0) && (gPress == true)) {
    myBus.sendNoteOff(1, (67 + pitchPot + octave), noteVol);
    gPress = false;
  }

  if ((a == 1) && (aPress == false)) {
    col1 = 0;
    col2 = 255;
    col3 = 255;
    myBus.sendControllerChange(1, 10, pan);
    myBus.sendNoteOn(1, (69 + pitchPot + tonalityPot  + octave), noteVol);
    aPress = true;
  }

  if ((a == 0) && (aPress == true)) {
    myBus.sendNoteOff(1, (69 + pitchPot + tonalityPot  + octave), noteVol);
    aPress = false;
  }

  if ((b == 1) && (bPress == false)) {
    col1 = 50;
    col2 = 250;
    col3 = 130;
    myBus.sendControllerChange(1, 10, pan);
    myBus.sendNoteOn(1, (71 + pitchPot + octave), noteVol);
    bPress = true;
  }

  if ((b == 0) && (bPress == true)) {
    myBus.sendNoteOff(1, (71 + pitchPot + octave), noteVol);
    bPress = false;
  }

  if ((C == 1) && (CPress == false)) {
    col1 = 200;
    col2 = 90;
    col3 = 75;
    myBus.sendControllerChange(1, 10, pan);
    myBus.sendNoteOn(1, (72 + pitchPot + octave), noteVol);
    CPress = true;
  }

  if ((C == 0) && (CPress == true)) {
    myBus.sendNoteOff(1, (72 + pitchPot + octave), noteVol);
    CPress = false;
  }

  if(c == 1 || d == 1 || e == 1 || f == 1 ||
     g == 1 || a == 1 || b == 1 || C == 1) {
    noteOn = 1;
  }
  else {
    noteOn = 0;
  }

  if (dlay == 1) {
    if (noteOn == 1) {
      passTime = millis() - saveTime;
      if (passTime > 1) {
        expand += 15;
         saveTime = millis();
      }
      strokeWeight(10);
      stroke(col1, col2, col3);
      noFill();
      ellipse((300+pan), 300 , expand, expand);
  }
  else {
    expand = noteVol*2;
    noteOn = 0;
  }

  fill(0, 0, 0, 100);
  rect(0, 0, 600, 600);
  fill(col1, col2, col3);
  lights();
  pushMatrix();
  translate(300+pan, 300);
  noStroke();
  sphere(noteOn*noteVol);
  popMatrix();
}
else if (reverb == 1) {
  fill(0, 0, 0, 100);
  rect(0, 0, 600, 600);
  fill(col1, col2, col3);
  lights();
  pushMatrix();
  translate(300, 300);
  rotate(frameCount / 50.0);
  star(0, 0, (noteOn*noteVol* 20), ((noteOn*noteVol)/20), 40);
  popMatrix();
}
else {
  fill(0, 0, 0, 100);
    rect(0,0, 600,600);
    fill(col1,col2, col3);
    lights();
    pushMatrix();
    translate(300+pan, 300);
    noStroke();
    sphere(noteOn*noteVol);
    popMatrix();
  }
}

void serialEvent(Serial port) {

  while (port.available() > 0) {
    serial = port.readStringUntil(end);
  }

  if (serial != null) {

    A = split(serial, ',');
    B = trim(A);
    c = Integer.parseInt(B[1]);
    d = Integer.parseInt(B[1]);
    e = Integer.parseInt(B[2]);
    f = Integer.parseInt(B[3]);
    g = Integer.parseInt(B[4]);
    a = Integer.parseInt(B[5]);
    b = Integer.parseInt(B[6]);
    C = Integer.parseInt(B[7]);

    pitchPot = Integer.parseInt(B[9]);
    tonalityPot = Integer.parseInt(B[10]);
    noteVol = Integer.parseInt(B[11]);
    pan = Integer.parseInt(B[12]);
    dlay = Integer.parseInt(B[13]);
    reverb = Integer.parseInt(B[14]);
    distort = Integer.parseInt(B[15]);
    octave = Integer.parseInt(B[16]);
  }
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code. If you're stuck and haven't gotten an answer, try eliminating the bits that aren't relevant to the question-- can you read just *anything* through the serial port? Instead of guessing where the problem is in the whole program, try taking out parts until you have a better idea.

Comment: I agree with kevinsa5. Take out everything except for your SerialEvent function and start adding things back. You may also want to try using "port.bufferUntil(end);" in your setup, and then just "readString()" in your SerialEvent function.

Answer (score 0):

serialEvent() does not seem to called by a serial event like the documentation says, at least on the Arduino platforms I am using.  It may work on some.  If it doesn't work, try just calling serialEvent in your main loop. I think that is equivalent anyway as there really are not interrupts for serial data.  You just have to read it and the idea was that the serialEvent function would be called every loop but it doesn't seem to work that way.

The SerialEvent Arduino documentation says:
"NB : Currently, serialEvent() is not compatible with the Esplora, Leonardo, or Micro", but I suspect the list should be longer.

Comment: Re *"serialEvent() does not seem to called by a serial event like the documentation says"*: It does, but the documentation is poorly written, the comments in the standard code example does not mention it, and the standard code example is misleading: Most readers will not register that serialEvent() is ***** ***line-oriented*** ******.  That is, a newline (whatever that is. ASCII 13?) is required before serialEvent is called. The canonical is *[Arduino "SerialEvent" example code doesn't work on my Arduino Nano. I can't receive serial data. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67013619/)*

Comment: For instance, it is not suitable for receiving scan codes from a [PS/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2_port) keyboard (that works well otherwise). The workaround is to make the calls to the serial functions directly from the *loop()* function.